# Add a role to a user with the selection menu discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I just have a question, I make a bot with discord and the users on the guild add their roles themself with a drop-down menu, for this, in my code, i have this module (with many others options):

```
class selectmenu(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)

    options=[
        discord.SelectOption(label="Happy", value=1),
        discord.SelectOption(label="Sad", value=2),
        discord.SelectOption(label="In love", value=3),
    ]

    @discord.ui.select(placeholder="Emotion", min_values=1, max_values=1, options=options, custom_id="selectmenu")
    async def select(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, select):
        user = interaction.user
        guild = interaction.guild
        select.disabled=True
        if select.values[0] == "1":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Happy")
            await user.add_roles(role)
            await interaction.response.send_message("Emotion Happy added!", ephemeral=True)
        
        elif select.values[0] == "2":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Sad")
            await user.add_roles(role)
            await interaction.response.send_message("Emotion Sad added", ephemeral=True)

        elif select.values[0] == "3":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="In love")
            await user.add_roles(role)
            await interaction.response.send_message("Emotion In love added", ephemeral=True)
```

This code is functional, but it is no efficient, let me explain:
there is is one condition per role but if we have 20 roles, we have 20 conditions, that takes too many lines of code!

If someone has a solution, even if it allows me to remove a dozen lines, it is good to take!
thanks to anyone who tries to help me

Answer (score 0):

To improve efficiency, you may want to consider using a dictionary to store your roles, with the menu selection as keys and the role names as values. For example:

```
roleDict = {'1': 'Happy', '2': 'Sad', '3': 'In Love'}
```

From this point, the dictionary can be implemented as follows:

```
role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = roleDict[<USER_SELECTION>])
await user.add_roles(role)
await interaction.response.send_message("Emotion " + roleDict[<USER_SELECTION>] + " added!", ephemeral=True)
```